# После Commit'a на SVN сервер программа работает иначе

Tags: svn, android, ide, java

Среда разработки IDEA. Программа у меня работает на компе, все хорошо. Делаю commit на SVN, потом скачиваю в другую папку то, что залил, запускаю и всё, как раньше не работает. Сверяю все файлы идентичны, а работать как раньше не хочет. Отличие в масштабировании картинок, у меня в версии на компе все хорошо, а ту, что заливал и скачал себе в другую папку, уже не масштабирует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один раз была похожая проблема, после того, как залил в SVN, прога не работала. Причина была в том, что в `classpath` добавлялись все файлы с папки `lib`, в том числе и служебная папка svn '.svn'.

P.S. У вас, скорее всего, проблема в другом. Может, у вас к некоторым файлам прописаны абсолютные пути?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Но можно поподробнее.

Comment: 1) ant скрипт запускался .bat файлом, который и устанавливал CLASSPATH примерно так:  
CLASSPATH = %CLASSPATH%:%LIB_DIR%/*

пока не закоммитили в SVN все работало, а потом стало падать так как немогло адекватно обработать папку '.svn' которая появилась внутри LIB_DIR

2) пример бока с абсолютным путем/относительным приводить да/нет ?:)